# Castle Windsor DynamicProxy Interception IInvocation Documentation

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, castle, castle-dynamicproxy

On a Castle Castle.DynamicProxy.IInvocation, what's the difference between

```
GetConcreteMethod

GetConcreteMethodInvocationTarget

Method
```

I read the documentation, but I don't understand the difference, especially between the first two.

I'm guessing that `Method` is just the MethodInfo for the method on the actual registered type?

Comment: What documentation are you referring to?  I checked the wiki at http://stw.castleproject.org/Tools.DynamicProxy.ashx and those methods don't appear anywhere (which is a different issue).

Comment: Xml documentation on the code itself (eg. intellisense)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- GetConcreteMethod returns a closed method on the **proxy**, closing it in case it has generic parameters. If it is not a generic method it will plainly return the same value as the Method property.
- GetConcreteMethodInvocationTarget returns the same value as the MethodInvocationTarget property, but in debug builds asserts that it returns a closed method definition.
- Method returns the MethodInfo of the **proxy**, not bothering to return a closed generic method.

Does this answer you question?

By the way, I've updated the Xml docs so hopefully they will be a bit more clear.

Comment: Thank you!! MethodInvocationTarget returns the MethodInfo on the registered service (not closed), correct?

Comment: MethodInvocationTarget returns the closed MethodInfo on the target (registered service)

Comment: Is there a way to get the method on the implementation? Not the proxy.

Comment: That's what you use GetConcreteMethodInvocationTarget() or MethodInvocationTarget for